# How to make jhipster react-js validateField select dropdown filterable?

Tags: reactjs, filter, jhipster

I have a small Jhipster-generated application. And the application frontend client is React.

The application has a relationship with another entity and on create/update page there's a select dropdown option. Jhipster used `<ValidatedForm> <\ValidatedForm>` for **Form** and **ValidateField** for input fields. I have this following dropdown **select** and I need the option to make it filterable. If I use React-Select or any other type of field then I cannot seem to make it work with the <`ValidateForm`>. How can I make this select field searchable/filterable?

Here's the code:

```
<ValidatedField id="recruitment-jobCircular" name="jobCircular" data-cy="jobCircular" label="Position" type="select" validate={{
    required: { value: true, message: 'This field is required.' },
    }}>
    <option value="" key="0" />
    { jobCirculars ? jobCirculars.map(otherEntity => (
     <option value={otherEntity.id} key={otherEntity.id}>
    {otherEntity.title}
    </option>
    ))
  : null}
</ValidatedField>
```

Comment: Have you figured it out?
Please share your solution if exists

Comment: @GaliloGalilo actually no, so I used Material UI for it.